After going on production my React website routes are not working
I have created a website using React and Vite (as a bundler). On my local host everything's working fine, but on production my routes are not working, and it's showing me 404 errors.
Every time I have to open my homepage only then after clicking on navbar tabs I can change my page and then routes are working. What am I doing wrong?

Without knowing any details, my crystal ball is saying the URL base is different in your production environment; e.g. you've been developing on http://127.0.0.1:5173/ but your production site is in a subdirectory, e.g https://anshika.site/foo/, and the router doesn't know about the subdirectory.

Do share your package.json. Also, which platform are you using for the deployment?

Your description suggests that your webserver is not correctly set up to handle routing for a single-page application (SPA). In a typical SPA, the frontend routing logic requires that the initial HTML file (usually index.html) containing your React application is served in response to all route requests. This setup is essential because it allows the React code to handle routing dynamically based on the URL present in the browser.
If you're developing a simple SPA with React, you'll want to ensure that your webserver consistently delivers the index.html file, which includes your bundled React application, for every requested route. This configuration allows your React app to interpret the URL and render the appropriate components without the need for additional requests to the server for each new route.
As an example, for an nginx server, you can achieve this by modifying your server configuration to direct all traffic to the index.html file:
location / {
    root /var/www/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

This configuration tells nginx to attempt to serve the requested URL or directory ($uri $uri/), and if it fails (i.e., the resource does not exist), it falls back to serving the /index.html file. This setup ensures that your React app is loaded and can then handle the routing as defined in your frontend code.

Try using HashRouter,
In your react project find the page where routes are configured, mostly main.jsx
replace BrowserRouter with HashRouter
import { HashRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

Rebuild your project!
